# Can the search refiner web part handle localized values?

Tags: search, managed-property, refiner

Using the BCS I am crawling external data and I am using Managed Properties to make sure that data is available in search results.  I can use the search refiner web part to refine based on one of my managed properties.

For simplicity sake, let's say the property is "Color".  The values might be "red", "green", or "blue" for English speakers, but they would be "rojo", "verde", or "azul" for Spanish speakers.  I would like the category name to show as "Color" in both languages only because they are the same (if French was used the category/refiner title might show "Couleur").

In my example (and for my real need) the list of colors is finite and relatively small (about 10).  The list of languages is also manageable such that I can have all of the values placed in the refiner web part's Filter Category Definition property (if that's where it would go).  In addition, I have an integer value for each color that is common across each language so I can use that to my advantage if needed (it can be the Managed Property as long as we show the word and not the number to the user).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will be hard. My best guess:
Create a separate search center/search page per language, and map your refiners on the locaized values. You should use a valuemapping + customfilter for this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819920.aspx

Using this technique, you can map the value 1 on, for example, red, rojo or rood. It requires you to know beforehand what values are possible, to map it in the correct way.

- When using a search center per language, you can localize the complete site for the user
- When using Fast as search engine, the custom value mapping *will not work*
- The way this refinement and metadata behaves, is normal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm still holding out for a silver bullet (so I'll let this sit for a day or two before marking this as the answer), but it sounds like your solution is our best option without writing code.  I believe I could build my own refiner web part that inherits from the original and make it work, but that isn't in the budget right now.

Comment: Actually it looks like a custom refinement filter is what would be needed to do the trick.   http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2011/03/29/building-a-custom-refinement-filter-generator-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: true, that should do the trick, but I always prefer to have no-code solutions. Your solution will be more manageable when there are a lot of changes expected

Comment: We already have a custom core search results web part, so another piece of code won't hurt us from that standpoint.  Just extra dev time and something else to maintain.

Comment: when overriding the refinement webpart, you can choose to replace values by localized ones, that;s a possibility too, then

Comment: that would be an option, but I think doing a custom refinement filter would be a cleaner approach (see link in comment above).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Codeplex-project:
[MUI Search Refinement Panel](http://ventigrate.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MUI%20Search%20Refinement%20Panel&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.